# Save UUID as String in Database with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

normally I store my UUID´s to the database as String. In Spring Boot 2.x I used to decoreate the UUID with `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")`. Somehow in Spring Boot 3.x it doesnt work anymore. It tells me `Cannot resolve method 'type'`.

I know there were some changes to jakarta but i dont know if this is a problem to me.

My Entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "werkstatt")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class WerkstattEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    private UUID id;
}
```

My gradle dep:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5'

    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'

    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you'll find if you read in the migration guide for Hibernate 6, we no longer use stringly-typed names to identify types. Which is much better.

But even better still, you no longer need a custom `@Type` annotation to persist `UUID`s. So:

```java
@Id
private UUID id;
```

would in principle work fine.

You can even use:

```java
@Id @GeneratedValue
private UUID id;
```

if you want the `UUID` to be generated.

However, note that, by default, this maps to a column of type `UUID` if the database has such a type. If you really need to map to a `VARCHAR` columns, use:

```java
@Id @GeneratedValue
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARCHAR)
private UUID id;
```

or:

```java
@Id @GeneratedValue
@JdbcType(VarcharJdbcType.class)
private UUID id;
```

depending on taste.

Comment: this absolutly works fine now! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I know there were some changes to jakarta but i dont know if this is a problem to me.

It probably is. The Jakarta Persistence API 3.1 now supports the `java.util.UUID` type ([here](https://newsroom.eclipse.org/eclipse-newsletter/2022/march/what%E2%80%99s-new-jakarta-persistence-31) and [here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.1.html#jakarta-persistence-3-1)).

Plotting the dependency tree in Maven (`mvn dependency:tree`) for the latest current version of Spring-Boot (`3.0.6`), you can see it uses `org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.1.7.Final` - which is [compatible](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/) with JPA 3.1.

Try removing `@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")` and `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")` annotations from your `WerkstattEntity` entity.

Be cautious, though: on an Apache Derby database, the `java.util.UUID` type is translated to `char(16) for bit data`.