# Hibernate to delegate UUID generation to postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Imagine I have a simple table such as the following, defined using a liquibase changeset

```xml
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd">
 
    <changeSet author="..." id="uuid-ossp-extension">
        <sql>CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"</sql>
    </changeSet>
 
    <changeSet author="example" id="widgets-table">
        <createTable tableName="widgets">
            <column name="widget_id" type="uuid" defaultValueComputed="uuid_generate_v1mc()">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="widget_pk"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(10)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
 
</databaseChangeLog>
```

That is, I want to be explicit about letting postgres compute the UUID.

If I was using Spring JdbcTemplate, I could use something simple like:

```java
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WidgetRepository {

    public static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO widgets(name) VALUES (:name)";


    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    public UUID saveAndReturn(Widget widget) {
        var params = new MapSqlParameterSource(Map.of("name", widget.getName());
        var generatedKeyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        var generateKeyColumns = new String[]{"widget_id"};
        template.update(INSERT_QUERY, params, generatedKeyHolder, generateKeyColumns);
        return generatedKeyHolder.getKeyAs(UUID.class);
    }

    ...

}
```

With Hibernate 6.0 onwards, there is a new [UuidGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/UuidGenerator.html) annotation, that simplifies Hibernate taking responsibility for generating a UUID:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "widgets")
public class Widget {
 
    @Id
    @UuidGenerator(style = TIME)
    @Column(name = "widget_id")
    private UUID id;
 
    @Column
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

However, this new UUIDGenerator mechanism doesn't seem to support delegating to postgres. https://vladmihalcea.com/uuid-identifier-jpa-hibernate/ suggested an alternative approach, but the [UUIDGenerationStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/UUIDGenerationStrategy.html) it implements is now deprecated.

Does anyone know the preferred mechanism for Hibernate 6.0 onwards?

Comment: Don't you think it actually looks like [GenerationTypeIDENTITY](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/#GenerationTypeIDENTITY) with the only difference you are using uuid instead of number?

Comment: The deprecated class states what to use for the replacement, use that instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum - the linked class it recommends is itself deprecated :)

Comment: Which again contains a link to the actual class you should use.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov thanks. That almost works, but complains with unrecognized id type : uuid -> java.util.UUID. In previous versions of hibernate, you could annotate with Type(type="pg-uuid"), but this has now been tightened to expect a class instead. Just searching to find what class pg-uuid was pointing at in the past..

Comment: @M.Deinum that class is for hibernate generated UUIDs, which is not what I was after.

Comment: Gavin King answered something similar yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76212860/3426309. I think `@JdbcType(UUIDJdbcType.class)` should help.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyB.Panfilov I will see if can get that working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweeted about this here:

https://twitter.com/1ovthafew/status/1645795161379831811

The short answer is:

```java
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Generated @Id
    @ColumnDefault("gen_random_uuid()")
    UUID uuid;
}
```

Note that Hibernate 6.2 is required.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to use GeneratedValue instead of Generated. But other than that, it seems to work fine!

Comment: Umm. I think `@GeneratedValue` would be generating the `UUID`s in memory. You need `@Generated` to tell Hibernate to fetch them from the database after the `INSERT`.

Comment: Oh. Then that didn't work for me :(

Comment: Well ... why not? I certainly did test that code on Postgres before tweeting it.

Comment: Hmm. It didn't seem to work when I used simply @Generated. I think it must be working from the database surely, since gen_random_uuid() only exists within the database? Let me see what the error was ...

Comment: Error was: annotation @Generated is missing a default value for the element 'value'

Comment: Ah, right, you might need 6.2, which has the whole new `Generator` framework. But in 6.1 you can try with `@Generated(INSERT)` and see if that works. (I have not tested this.)